# Preventing a second legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a ggplot, which also displays a legend:

```
ggplot(dt.m, aes(x=pct.on.OAC.cont,y=Number.of.Practices, fill=Age.Group)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity",position=position_dodge())
```

When I add another line, I also get a second legend:

```
geom_smooth(aes(x=pct.on.OAC.cont,y=Number.of.Practices, colour=Age.Group), se=F, alpha=0.5)
```

How can I prevent the second legend from displaying ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `show_guide = FALSE` in `geom_smooth`:

```
geom_smooth(aes(x=pct.on.OAC.cont,y=Number.of.Practices, colour=Age.Group),
            se=F, alpha=0.5, show_legend = FALSE)
```

This suppresses drawing a legend.

Comment: In the new ggplot2, the command is show.legend = FALSE. But everything else is the same.