# Turning off some legends in a ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suppose I have a ggplot with more than one legend.

```
mov <- subset(movies, length != "")
(p0 <- ggplot(mov, aes(year, rating, colour = length, shape = mpaa)) +
  geom_point()
)
```

I can turn off the display of all the legends like this:

```
(p1 <- p0 + theme(legend.position = "none"))
```

Passing `show_guide = FALSE` to `geom_point` (as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12746523/preventing-a-second-legend)) turns off the shape legend.

```
(p2 <- ggplot(mov, aes(year, rating, colour = length, shape = mpaa)) +
  geom_point(show_guide = FALSE)
)
```

But what if I want to turn off the colour legend instead?  There doesn't seem to be a way of telling `show_guide` which legend to apply its behaviour to.  And there is no `show_guide` argument for scales or aesthetics.

```
(p3 <- ggplot(mov, aes(year, rating, colour = length, shape = mpaa)) +
  scale_colour_discrete(show_guide = FALSE) +
  geom_point()
)
# Error in discrete_scale

(p4 <- ggplot(mov, aes(year, rating, shape = mpaa)) +
  aes(colour = length, show_guide = FALSE) +
  geom_point()
)
#draws both legends
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393123/controlling-ggplot2-legend-display-order) suggests that the modern (since ggplot2 v0.9.2) way of controlling legends is with the `guides` function.

I want to be able to do something like

```
p0 + guides(
  colour = guide_legend(show = FALSE) 
)
```

but `guide_legend` doesn't have a show argument.

How do I specify which legends get displayed?

Comment: After a recent ``ggplot2`` update, ``show_guide`` has been deprecated and replaced by ``show.legend``.

Answer (score 397, accepted):

You can use `guide = "none"` in `scale_..._...()` to suppress legend.

For your example you should use `scale_colour_continuous()` because `length` is continuous variable (not discrete).

```
(p3 <- ggplot(mov, aes(year, rating, colour = length, shape = mpaa)) +
   scale_colour_continuous(guide = "none") +
   geom_point()
)
```

Or using function `guides()` you should set `"none"` for that element/aesthetic that you don't want to appear as legend, for example, `fill`, `shape`, `colour`.

```
p0 <- ggplot(mov, aes(year, rating, colour = length, shape = mpaa)) +
  geom_point()    
p0+guides(colour = "none")
```

### UPDATE

Both provided solutions work in new `ggplot2` version 3.3.5 but `movies` dataset is no longer present in this library. Instead you have to use new package `ggplot2movies` to check those solutions.

```
library(ggplot2movies)
data(movies)
mov <- subset(movies, length != "")
```

Comment: The scale_colour_continuous(guide = FALSE) does not work in ggplot2 0.9.3 but guides(colour=FALSE) solves the issue. Thanks a lot Didzis!

Comment: @NikolayNenov Strange, because both solutions works for me with ggplot2 0.9.3.1

Comment: I want to remove **legend of alpha**. `guides(alpha=FALSE)` do the trick. Thank you, Didzis.

Comment: Note to self: if you have a ``geom_linerange()`` and the legend is showing a cross instead of a line, insert ``show.legend=FALSE`` inside the ``geom_linerange()``.

Comment: Suggested update: `guide = FALSE` is deprecated and was replaced by `guide = "none"`.

Answer (score 79):

You can simply add `show.legend=FALSE` to geom to suppress the corresponding legend

Comment: Worked very well!

Comment: Exactly what I was searching for

Comment: This deserves a thread of its own. Thanks mate.