# Remove legend ggplot 2.2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm trying to keep the legend of one layer (smooth) and remove the legend of the other (point). I have tried shutting off the legends with `guides(colour = FALSE)` and `geom_point(aes(color = vs), show.legend = FALSE)`.

**Edit**: As this question and its answers are popular, a reproducible example seems in order:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = disp, group = gear)) +
geom_point(aes(color = vs)) +
geom_point(aes(shape = factor(cyl))) +
geom_line(aes(linetype = factor(gear))) +
geom_smooth(aes(fill = factor(gear), color = gear)) + 
theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: A minimal reproducible example would be far simpler. In the long line of code there appears to be a lot of unnecessary (to the problem at hand) code as well as it being entirely unreproducible as it currently is written.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turning off some legends in a ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604435/turning-off-some-legends-in-a-ggplot)

Answer (score 629):

from [r cookbook](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_(ggplot2)/), where bp is your ggplot:

Remove legend for a particular aesthetic (fill):

```
bp + guides(fill="none")
```

It can also be done when specifying the scale:

```
bp + scale_fill_discrete(guide="none")
```

This removes all legends:

```
bp + theme(legend.position="none")
```

Comment: As a reply to a comment by @Alex:

Note that `theme_bw()` can interfere with any definitions done using `theme()`. When using `theme_bw()`, make sure to add it to the plot before you alter any other theme options.

Comment: but when I do something like this `bp + theme(legend.position="none") + theme_classic()`, the legends come back. So how to remove it?

Comment: @loveR put theme_classic first: `bp + theme_classic() + theme(legend.position="none")`

Comment: This had no effect on my plot. I used @Tjebo 's approach successfully.

Comment: For the middle example, `guide=FALSE` has been deprecated. Now they suggest using `guide="none"`

Answer (score 121):

There might be another solution to this:
Your code was:

```
geom_point(aes(..., show.legend = FALSE))
```

You can specify the `show.legend` parameter *after* the `aes` call:

```
geom_point(aes(...), show.legend = FALSE)
```

then the corresponding legend should disappear

Comment: This is a very nice approach. More intuitive as well.

Comment: This was the solution that worked to remove letters from the legend when I used geom_text to annotate lines in color.  There is no ``scale_label`` command (nor does this make sense), and ``guide(label = FALSE)`` also did not work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 76):

As the question and **user3490026**'s answer are a top search hit, I have made a reproducible example and a brief illustration of the suggestions made so far, together with a solution that explicitly addresses the OP's question.

One of the things that `ggplot2` does and which can be confusing is that it automatically blends certain legends when they are associated with the same variable. For instance, `factor(gear)` appears twice, once for `linetype` and once for `fill`, resulting in a combined legend. By contrast, `gear` has its own legend entry as it is not treated as the same as `factor(gear)`. The solutions offered so far usually work well. But occasionally, you may need to override the guides. See my last example at the bottom.

```
# reproducible example:
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = disp, group = gear)) +
geom_point(aes(color = vs)) +
geom_point(aes(shape = factor(cyl))) +
geom_line(aes(linetype = factor(gear))) +
geom_smooth(aes(fill = factor(gear), color = gear)) + 
theme_bw()
```

[image]

**Remove all legends: @user3490026**

```
p + theme(legend.position = "none")
```

**Remove all legends: @duhaime**

```
p + guides(fill = "none", color = "none", linetype = "none", shape = "none")
```

**Turn off legends: @Tjebo**

```
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = disp, group = gear)) +
geom_point(aes(color = vs), show.legend = FALSE) +
geom_point(aes(shape = factor(cyl)), show.legend = FALSE) +
geom_line(aes(linetype = factor(gear)), show.legend = FALSE) +
geom_smooth(aes(fill = factor(gear), color = gear), show.legend = FALSE) + 
theme_bw()
```

**Remove fill so that linetype becomes visible**

```
p + guides(fill = "none")
```

**Same as above via the `scale_fill_discrete` function:**

```
p + scale_fill_discrete(guide = "none")
```

And now one possible answer to the OP's request:

> "to keep the legend of one layer (smooth) and remove the legend of the
> other (point)"

**Turn some on some off ad-hoc post-hoc**

```
p + guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(color = NA)), 
           color = "none", 
           shape = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: Just noticed the blue fill color in the last plot doesn't appear on the graph, not sure why...

Comment: Type `warnings()` after you ran your code and you' ll see the reason(s) for the blue ribbon not showing up.

Comment: @markus: Got it thanks! I won't bother to edit the example, since the issue is separate. However, it makes little sense to have a legend for ``se`` when it is not computed. Probably worth an issue at github, but I don't have the energy right now...

Answer (score 16):

If your chart uses both `fill` and `color` aesthetics, you can remove the combined legend with:

```
+ guides(fill="none", color="none")
```