# use ggplot2 to make a bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

my data looks like this and I want to create a bar plot

```
     services percent
1     overall  80.00%
2   service 1  50.00%
3   service 2  43.00%
4   service 3  45.00%
5   service 4  78.00%
6   service 5  34.00%
7   service 6  78.00%
8   service 7  23.00%
9   service 8  54.00%
10  service 9  32.00%
11 service 10  32.00%
```

here is what I tried

```
ggplot(service, aes(fill=services, y=percent, x=services)) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") + 
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Now I want to revise the chart with

1. keep the y-axis in the original order
2. remove the legend
3. force the x-axis on a 100% scale

Comment: I recommend a course in google. question 1) https://stackoverflow.com/q/25664007/7941188 question 2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35618260/remove-legend-ggplot-2-2 question 3) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563368/create-stacked-barplot-where-each-stack-is-scaled-to-sum-to-100

Comment: @Dr. Know Nothing. When you look at your chart you should notice that the height of the bars doesn't match the values in  column `percent`. The scale is discrete, not continuous as you might expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#Code
df %>%
  mutate(percent=as.numeric(gsub('%','',percent))/100,
         services=factor(services,levels = rev(unique(services)),ordered = T))%>%
  ggplot(aes(fill=services, y=percent, x=services)) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent,limits = c(0,1))+
  coord_flip()+
  theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

Output:

[image]

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(services = c("overall", "service 1", "service 2", 
"service 3", "service 4", "service 5", "service 6", "service 7", 
"service 8", "service 9", "service 10"), percent = c("80.00%", 
"50.00%", "43.00%", "45.00%", "78.00%", "34.00%", "78.00%", "23.00%", 
"54.00%", "32.00%", "32.00%")), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: just a follow up question, how can I keep the y-axis in the original order? like from top to the bottom "overall, service 1,.....service 10"?

Comment: @Dr.KnowNothing I will update the code now!

Comment: @Dr.KnowNothing I have updated the code for you. Please check and let me know if that works for you. Also check the info I shared with you!

Comment: perfect. Thanks a lot! I will figure out what each line stands for! this is SUPER helpful!

Comment: @Dr.KnowNothing Please consider accepting this answer if it was helpful!

Comment: I'd love to but it seems like I don't have enough 'reputation' it says "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."....

Comment: @Dr.KnowNothing You can, you have to click the tick on the left side of the answer so that it turns green. That is how you accept an answer.