# Colour average lines in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, average

I would like to colour the dashed lines, which are the average values of the two respective categories, with the same colour of the default palette used by `ggplot` to fill the distributions:

[Click here to view the distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snFDY.png)

This is the code used:

```
library(ggplot2)

print(ggplot(dati, aes(x=ECU_fuel_consumption_L_100Km_CF, fill=Model))
  + ggtitle("Fuel Consumption density histogram, by Model")
  + ylab("Density")
  + geom_density(alpha=.3)
  + scale_x_continuous(breaks=pretty(dati$ECU_fuel_consumption_L_100Km_CF, n=10))
  + geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mean(ECU_fuel_consumption_L_100Km_CF[dati$Model == "500X"])), linetype="dashed", size=1)
  + geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mean(ECU_fuel_consumption_L_100Km_CF[dati$Model == "Renegade"])), linetype="dashed", size=1)
)
```

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No reproducible example, but you probably want to do something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
# make up some data
d <- data.frame(x = c(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$hp),
                var = rep(c('mpg', 'hp'), each = nrow(mtcars)))
means <- d %>% group_by(var) %>% summarize(m = mean(x))

ggplot(d, aes(x, fill = var)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_vline(data = means, aes(xintercept = m, col = var), 
             linetype = "dashed", size = 1)
```

This approach is extendable to any number of groups.

An option that doesn't require pre-calculation, but is also a bit more hacky, is:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x, fill = var)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_vline(aes(col = 'hp', xintercept = x), linetype = "dashed", size = 1,
             data = data.frame(x = mean(d$x[d$var == 'hp']))) +
  geom_vline(aes(col = 'mpg', xintercept = x), linetype = "dashed", size = 1,
             data = data.frame(x = mean(d$x[d$var == 'mpg'])))
```

Comment: Thank you, the second option worked well; but I had to remove an additional legend appeared [how to turn off some legends](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604435/turning-off-some-legends-in-a-ggplot)