# ggplot2 remove linetype legend but keep color legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have an R script to make a graph with `ggplot2`. To make a real reproducible example is a bit complicated but the code to make the plot is the following:

```
 ggplot(df,aes(x=Year,y=value, colour = factor(mpft)), show.legend = T) +
      geom_line(aes(group = index, linetype=LETTERS[df$type]), size = .8) +
      scale_linetype_manual(name= "Run Type", values=lty.stock(seqle(run.type)),labels = run.type) +
      scale_color_manual(name = "PFT",
                         values = setNames(mycol[unique(df$mpft)], unique(df$mpft)),
                         labels = setNames(mynam[unique(df$mpft)], unique(df$mpft))) +
      scale_linetype_manual(name= "Run Type", values=lty.stock(seqle(run.type)),labels = run.type) +
...
```

[image]

How can I disable only the linetype legend possibly by a giving it a boolean condition. Something like

```
  scale_color_manual(..., show = TRUE) +
  scale_linetype_manual(..., show = FALSE) +
```

**EDIT**

Since a user is pointing at the similarity with [Turning off some legends in a ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604435/turning-off-some-legends-in-a-ggplot)
I underline the fact that the dropping of the legend should depend upon a boolean condition. In that post the `guide = FALSE` option is used. This actually gives also here the correct result, however `guide = TRUE` produces an error.
This can be overcome by using something like

```
p = ggplot() + ...
if(condition) p = p + guides(linetype = FALSE)
```

It's not exactly what I was looking for but I guess it does the trick.

Comment: Check this page: http://zevross.com/blog/2014/08/04/beautiful-plotting-in-r-a-ggplot2-cheatsheet-3/#working-with-the-legend It was very usefull for me when working with ggplot.

Comment: There's a lot of useful stuff but I couldn't find anything that really suits my needs...

Comment: Can't check without reproducible example, but you can also try `ggplot(...) + ... + scale_*_manual(legend = ifelse(BOOL, 'legend', 'none'))`.