# How can I change the legend in fviz_silhouette?

Tags: r, ggplot2, cluster-analysis

I am trying to generate some silhouette with a R library called "factoextra".
Unfortunately, I end up in a problem.
Let's look at the following example with the "iris" dataset.

```
library(factoextra)
library(cluster)
set.seed(123)
data("iris")
iris.scaled <- scale(iris[, -5])
# K-means clustering

km.res <- kmeans(iris.scaled, 3, nstart = 2)
# Visualize silhouhette information
sil <- silhouette(km.res$cluster, dist(iris.scaled))
fviz_silhouette(sil)+
  scale_fill_discrete(labels=c("a","b","c"))
```

I tried to add a specific legend "a","b","c". [image: Example of double legend]

As you can see the legend duplicate, showing "a","b","c" and then "1","2","3".  Is there a way to show only "a","b","c"?

Comment: Have you tried `+ theme(legend.position="none")` before your `scale_fill_discrete()`?

Comment: If I do that all the legends disappear.

Comment: You might find a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604435/turning-off-some-legends-in-a-ggplot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply remove the `color` guide:

```
sil <- silhouette(km.res$cluster, dist(iris.scaled))
fviz_silhouette(sil)+
  scale_fill_discrete(labels=c("a","b","c"))+
  guides(col=FALSE)
```

If you look at the source code, you can see this line that controls the mappings:

```
mapping <- aes_string(x = "name", y = "sil_width", 
        color = "cluster", fill = "cluster")
```

Setting a discrete fill and removing the color yields the expected plot.

Result:

[image]