# Lollipop chart with multiple groupings: how to remove and alter legends?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

The below **lollipop chart** is made using `ggplot2`. I use`facet_wrap` to get small multiples, one per group. I use `geom_point` to color the dots differently so to highlight differences across a second way of grouping. I hence get **two legends**: one made with 'facet_wrap' (groups A-C) and one made with 'geom_point' ('fruit', 'meat', 'vegetables').

*How can I remove the legend made with facet_wrap, but keep the other? And how can we alter the title of the remaining one?*

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604435/turning-off-some-legends-in-a-ggplot) seems not to help with a legend produced by facet_wrap.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(plyr)

# create sample data
group <- c("A","A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A","B","B","B","B", "B", "B", "B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C")
keycol <- c("var1a", "var1b","var1c", "var2a", "var2b","var3a","var3b","var3c","var3d","var1a", "var1b","var1c", "var2a", "var2b","var3a","var3b","var3c","var3d","var1a", "var1b","var1c", "var2a", "var2b","var3a","var3b","var3c","var3d")
valuecol <-c(0,0.1,0.4,0.6,0.4,0.7,0.2,0.7,0.1,0,1,0.6,0.2,0.5,0,0.3,0.4,0.1,0,0.8,0.5,0.3,0.6,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.1)

mydata <- data.frame(group, keycol, valuecol)

# create the lollipop plot

p <- ggplot(mydata, aes(y = keycol, x = valuecol, fill = group)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0, y = keycol, xend = valuecol, yend = keycol), color = "grey50") +
  geom_point(aes(color=ifelse(keycol %in% c("var2a","var2b"), "fruit",
                              ifelse(keycol %in% c("var1a","var1b", "var1c"), "meat", "vegetables"))), size = 3) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),axis.title.y = element_blank(),legend.position = "bottom") +
  facet_wrap(~group)
p
```

[image: Comparing Multiple Points of Information]

1. I would like to remove the legend on the groups A-C; information is
   redundant.
2. I would like to change the title of the color legend.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The title is fairly direct, choose from among:

```r
p +
  scale_color_discrete(guide="none")
```

[image: no legend]

```r
p +
  scale_color_discrete(name = "New Name")
```

[image: new legend title]

... and to remove the last, realize that it is just another scale (fill), so we remove it in the same fashion:

```r
p +
  scale_color_discrete(name = "New Name") +
  scale_fill_discrete(guide = "none")
```

[image: third plot]

Comment: Thanks! Brilliant for the second sub-question :-) Do you happen to know how I can also remove the other legend, i.e. the one with the groups A-C? Thanks!!

Comment: @r2evans it sounds like the OP wants to remove the group legend and keep the coloue legend. The best way to do this is not specify fill = group in the initial ggplot call. This is what is causing the unwanted legend - not the faceting.

Comment: Allan, yup, thanks, I realized that after I posted. TiF, hope this answers your question, I think the edit finishes it.

Comment: Thanks so much for the speedy answer! That was very helpful! Great.

Comment: Sorry, TiF, removed an errant line of code (`scale_shape`), was playing/testing and copied the wrong code over.